# How to use MobileDevice.Framework in MAC

Tags: macos

How can I access the `MobileDevice.Framework` classes in MAC?

Comment: Do you mean on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple did not release any documentation because this framework is private.

Check this page for the header and available functions:
http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=MobileDevice_Library

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look at [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) as it's an opensource version of the MobileDevice private framework.

Apps that use private frameworks are subject to getting the rug pulled out from under them at any time if that framework changes.